# React Admin removes filter box after "no results" list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I'm working with React Admin and I have a list with a box to filter by ID.

I filter by ID 0000 (for example), it returns "theres not data yet", but it removes my filter box and I can't restart filters or change it.

I would like to avoid React Admin to set this "Empty" view, and I have read about param "empty", I pass empty param to the List component, but I get nothing different.

```
              <List
              {...props}
              actions={<ListActions hasCreate={false} maxResults={MAX_LIMIT_EXPORT} />}
              filters={<Filter translate={translate} permissions={permissions} />}
              pagination={<Pagination />}
              bulkActionButtons={false}
              empty={<div>No results found</div>}
            >
```

I just want to handle what happends after receive an "empty" response, to keep my filters visible.

Comment: Try setting empty=false

Comment: No, that will just disable the empty message. The need here is to display a custom one. But within filtering seems that we can't…

Comment: Check out my answer down below. You may be able to get the functionality you want by adding some props to your Pagination component

Answer (score 1):

The ReactAdmin documentation about [`List#empty`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#empty-empty-page-component) prop says it all:

> When there is no result, **and there is no active filter**, and the
> resource has a create page, react-admin displays a special page
> inviting the user to create the first record.

I'm struggle with the same exact issue. I wonder if you have a solution now?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `limit` prop to your pagination component. ([React-Admin pagination docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#building-a-custom-pagination-control))

```
<List {...props}
  pagination={<Pagination limit={<div>No Results Found</div>} />}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you fetch a list, the response follows this schema

```
export interface GetManyDefaultResponse<T> {
    data: T[];
    count: number;
    total: number;
    page: number;
    pageCount: number;
}
```

If you have access to the backend, in the case of no results, you need to return the total field with value > 0
([], count: 0, total: 1, page: 0, pageCount: 0)

If you have no access to the backend, then you may want to override the response via dataProvider (getMany)